# find documents in MongoDB with set of keys

Tags: mongodb

assuming I have MongoDB with two collections A and B where, A has a attribute referencing a list of B:

A:

```
 {
   _id: ObjectId
   name : String
   itemB : [ObjectId]     
 }
```

B:

```
 {
   _id: ObjectId
   data : String 
   info : [String]
 }
```

What would be better to get all "data" from B for a given A:

a) read Array itemB from A, do .find( { _id: x } ) for each element x

b) read Array itemB from A, do .find( { _id : { $in: [ x1, x2, ...] }}) for the Array

Or is there even a better way to model this?
Reason to split it into A and B is that B.info can either have many items or B.data can be really long. Which means embedding B into A might cause performance issues because of max document size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to to store the relation the "other way" around:

A:

```
 {
   _id: ObjectId
   name : String
 }
```

B:

```
 {
   _id: ObjectId
   data : String 
   info : [String]
   itemA: ObjectId
 }
```

Then you can simply query:

```
db.B.find( { itemA: … } );
```

This query will **also** work if itemA is an array:

```
 {
   _id: ObjectId
   data : String 
   info : [String]
   itemA: [ ObjectId, ObjectId, … ]
 }
```

In MongoDB you tend to end up storing the "foreign keys" on the other side compared to a relational database.

Comment: I see the motivation in this. However, in my case, B is not associated with a single A, it could be a 1:n or n:m relation. Rather A1 has a list of Bs, and A2 has another list of Bs. In your case, B will also be associated to a single A?

Comment: Yes, in my example it does. But itemA can also easily be an array and the query will still work.

Comment: I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Yes, this works. But basically, I then have the problem vice versa on the other side. The actual usage of this is: For a given A, find all linked B documents. For a given B, find all linked A documents. - For the first, I can use your query. For the second, I can just read out the itemA array and then use the Ids there to find each A document. But this is my original question: Which of my options in my question (a or b) would be better or doesnt it matter at all?